# Are these waves coherent?

Tags: waves, coherence

[image]

- Are these two sinusoidal waves coherent?

Note that it is **not** on y-t graph. And $x_1 \neq x_2$ but time taken to cover both the distances is same *(which means same frequency)*.

i.e. $t_1 = t_2$
$$x_1/v_1 = x_2/v_2$$

And ofcourse constant phase difference.

The kind of wave I am talking about is [this](http://scienceprimer.com/embed/waveType.min.html) (transverse). Here direction of propagation of wave is $x$. And the wave can propagate with different frequencies and different speeds.

I think that they are coherent because they satisfy the necessary conditions *(i.e. same frequency and constant phase difference)*.

Comment: I think we are not on the same page on the definition of frequency for a standing wave. Same frequency and phase are not the required conditions of coherence, but, coherence needs a constant phase relation over a period of time.

Comment: @AminR. Please elaborate more. What is the difference between the definition i understand (same definition on (wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)] )and the real defination?

Comment: Try to clarify your question. Are these two standing waves with different length? What do you mean by "but time taken to cover both the distances is same"?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understand from your question that a particle is moving on the two paths above, you can assume that particle as an oscillating pen on a straight line and a paper moving underneath this pen continuously. The same pattern as your graphs then are generated with exception that they continue for several wavelengths. The faster the pen oscillates, bigger frequency, the shorter is the path, your right graph.

But the definition of coherence depends on the phase of this pen. Assume than if you are oscillating the pen with your hands, if you randomly change the direction of your hand (but still keep it on same straight line, just change the direction) then your sinusoidal graph will not be smooth and continuous and will have jumps. This means that you are randomly changing the phase of your pen. The time interval that you keep the direction of the move continuous is called the coherence time. During this period interference with another coherent wave will give you predictable graph shape. And beyond that time the graph is not predictable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not coherent. What you described above are two waves that May have the same frequency but obviously one travels faster than the other.

Comment: No. I have stated there that the time taken by the waves to cover their respective distances are same. So no wave is faster than the other here.

Comment: If they travel different distances in the same amount of time then obviously one is traveling faster than the other. Your graph shows different distances.

Comment: Yes, velocity of left wave is more than that of right wave.